# Entity Framework 5.0 SaveChanges of Complex objects

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have a method that accepts an input parameter for a list of transactions with added or updated records.

I loop through the list to discover which is modified and whish is added using the:
context.Entry(item).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
to set the state of each transaction.

The problem I have is because the transaction object has a relationship with TransactionType while I loop through the input parameter list of transactions, if there are more than one transaction with the same transaction id in the database I get the following error:

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.
>   The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same
>   key.

- By the way I am using EF5 and Code First.

The method in concern is:

```
public TransactionList SaveTransactions(Transaction[] transactions)
        {
            try
            {
                using (EntityContext context = new EntityContext())
                {
                    foreach (var item in transactions)
                    {
                        if (item.TransactionId > 0)
                            context.Entry(item).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
                        else
                            context.Entry(item).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
                    }

                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
                return GetLatestTransactions();
            }
```

**## UPDATE ##**
if I set the TransactionType for each item to null, I wont get any error and the rest of the transaction fields will be updated fine. i.e. TransAmount, Date, etc. The problem is that by setting the TransType to null I will never be able to change the type of my transaction.

```
using (EntityContext context = new EntityContext())
{
  foreach (var item in transactions)
  {
    //set the fk to null
    item.TransactionType = null;

    if (item.TransactionId > 0)
    {
      context.Entry(item).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
    }
    else
      context.Entry(item).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

**## UPDATE 2 ##**
I just found another way that this would work but still is not the ideal for me. I get the single transaction per item and then set the values. I don't like this solution since .Single will do a roundtrip for each iteration.

```
foreach (var item in transactions)
{
  var or = context.Transaction
  .Include(t => t.Category)
  .Include(t => t.TransactionReasonType)
  .Include(t => t.TransactionType)
  .Single(t => t.TransactionId == item.TransactionId);

  if (item.TransactionId > 0)
  {
    context.Entry(or).CurrentValues.SetValues(item);
    context.Entry(or).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
  }
```

Comment: If the source has Duplicates you should resolve this issue first.

Comment: The duplication is only on the foreign key. i.e. two different transactions might have the same TransactionType. I wont have the same transaction key more than once in my param or db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem was to separate the add from the update. For update, fetch each row from database set the original values with the new ones. For add just add the new values to the context.

```
foreach (var item in transactions)
{
  if (item.TransactionId > 0) //Update
  {
    var original = context.Transaction.Where(
                            t => t.TransactionId == item.TransactionId)
                          .FirstOrDefault();

    original.TransactionType = context.TypeTransaction.Single(
                           p => p.TypeTransactionId == item.TransactionType.TypeTransactionId);

    context.Entry(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(item);
  }
  else //Insert
  {    
    item.TransactionType = context.TypeTransaction.Single(
                           p => p.TypeTransactionId == item.TransactionType.TypeTransactionId);

    context.Transaction.Add(item);
  }
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to workaround this issue:

```
foreach (var item in updated)
{
   var original = db.MyEntities.Find(item.Id);
   db.Entry(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(item);
}
db.SaveChanges();
```